# ATMega328P Timer Problem in Proteus

Tags: avr, atmega, timer, proteus

I have an ATMega328P microcontroller, and I'm learning how it is programmed. I wrote an example for Timer0 and uploaded it into the microcontroller. It works and a led blinks once a second in while.

When I try to simulate it in Proteus 8.0, the led blinks every 8 seconds. I set the properties of the microcontroller in Proteus but nothing was changed. Why is the Timer0 delayed in Proteus?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now, I set it as "Unprogrammed".

Answer (score 1):

By default, the CLKDIV8 fuse bit is programmed, dividing the internal 8MHz oscillator down to 1MHz. It should be unprogrammed.